Why is WinForms not keeping control aspect ratio set in Designer?
I'm designing a form in WinForms (C#) and having a problem where a panel that is designed to be square is vertically stretched at runtime.
Here's how it looks in Designer (note the square panel on the right):
designer-form
Here's how it looks at runtime (note that the panel is no longer square):
runtime-form
What could be causing this distortion? And how can I prevent it?
Things to note:

The panel is actually being stretched (width and height changed); it's not just an illusion or non-square physical pixels. Know this from peeking the dimensions in debugging.
Using a 4k monitor.
ApplicationHighDpiMode is set to SystemAware, and ForceDesignerDpiUnaware is set to true.

Looked for some kind of control property that would force WinForms to honor the aspect ratio I set on controls in Designer when DPI scaling, but I couldn't find anything like that. Maybe it's a newbie misunderstanding, but it seems very odd to me that WinForms wouldn't just scale forms/controls equally on X and Y by default...

Why would you design in a non-DpiAware environment, when you want to produce a DpiAware application? That kind of environment is more common when you're porting an old application, created in .NET Framework, to .NET 6+, keeping it Dpi-Unaware, so you don't have to fight with the UI layout while you're adjusting the code. If you design a new application, do that without tampering with the default  DpiAwareness of Visual Studio, and generate a PerMonitorV2 DpiAware application. Then, you have to decide whether you want to scale to Font or Dpi, and plan your layout based on that choice

Was having a winforms issue that was annoyingly messing with my control sizing/positioning, so I just kinda mindlessly followed the suggested solution. I would try your suggestion, but I'm afraid that unsetting ForceDesignerDpiUnaware will make it start misbehaving again.

Forcing DpiUnaware mode doesn't solve anything, just hides a problem, last resort when you cannot do anything about it, because of constraint imposed in specific contexts. The example you see in the docs refers to people that, for some reason, work on the same UI project (and all work in the Designer, not just in code files) but with different screen settings. Great idea -- If this is the first time you design a WinForms DpiAware application, try first to design at 100% scale (VS can scale its UI, you can configure its Font size). See whether AutoScaleMode = Dpi makes it easier [...]

Use nested containers to layout your controls. Make use of FlowLayoutPanel and TableLayoutPanel containers, all can be set to auto-scale their content (they're not perfect, takes some time get it right). Use Anchoring and Docking, also setting the MinimumSize of containers and child controls that may require this. If you have to deal with different languages, consider that the width (and height) of some auto-sizing controls (e.g., Labels) is going to change, at some point; make sure the text is not cut off when this happens

BTW, you haven't actually said what problem you were trying to solve, in relation to your layout, so these suggestions are generic. Anyway, this all requires a lot of testing, and some patience

AutoScaleMode was set to Font by default. Just switched it to Dpi and it seems to have solved my problem! Something I forgot to mention: I work with 2 monitors: A laptop and a desktop monitor, which have different resolutions and such. I think working across both those monitors was causing me to bump into that issue I linked. Nonetheless, I'll continue to work with that setup, so I will keep forcing DpiUnaware mode for Designer. I will proceed cautiously though and keep your other tips in mind, in case this ends up screwing me later.

↑ try first to design at 100% scale! (at least until you get the gist of it)

@Jimi and when he got the gist of it he knows why he want to stay at 100% for designing. The warning in VS is there for a reason.
